# How can I do an AJAX request with Typescript? (using JSON)

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, typescript

I'm learning AJAX and I'm trying to do an AJAX request with parameters, but I'm having problems to send the JSON data:

I'm using Typescript and PHP (with Codeigniter), the idea is to create a Typescript object and send it to the PHP in JSON format. So basically I create an object and use the stringify method that I find on Google to convert this object to JSON (or a string in form of JSON I should say?) and send it to the server with AJAX, but the data is not arriving properly.

I used `print_r($_POST);` to see what is the server receiving and it shows to me the following:

```
Array
(
    [{"_dificultad_seleccionada":"Normal"}] => 
    [0] => 
)
```

The entire string that I get from stringify is shown as the key and the value is empty.

I don't understand very well what is happening, isn't stringify the way to convert an object to JSON and send it to the server? Why it isn't sending the object properly?

### Client code:

**Dificultad.ts** (class that I want to send to the server)

```
class Dificultad {

    private _dificultad_seleccionada: string;

    constructor (dificultad_seleccionada: string) {
        this._dificultad_seleccionada = dificultad_seleccionada;
    }

    get dificultad_seleccionada(): string {
        return this._dificultad_seleccionada;
    }

    set dificultad_seleccionada(dificultad_seleccionada: string) {
        this._dificultad_seleccionada = dificultad_seleccionada;
    }

}
```

**Lib.ts** (where I declare all const, DOM elements, etc.)

```
const BASE_URL: string = window.location.origin + "/Project_name/";
type CallbackFunction = (arg: any, ...args: any[]) => void;
```

**Main.ts** (here is where I send the AJAX)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $( "a#boton_seleccion_dificultad" ).click(function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            if (pasapalabra.gameState == GameState.GAME_STARTING) {

                let _dificultad: Dificultad = new Dificultad("Normal");
                sendAjaxRequest("POST", "get_dificultad_seleccionada", JSON.stringify(_dificultad), function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });

            }

        });

    });

function sendAjaxRequest(_type: string, _url: string, _params: string, _callback: CallbackFunction) {

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: _type,
        url: BASE_URL + _url,
        data: _params,
        contentType: 'json'
    });
    request.done(function(res) {
        _callback(res);
    });
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.error(jqXHR)
        _callback({ err: true, message: "Request failed: " + textStatus });
    });

}
```

### Server code:

**Welcome.php**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library("grocery_CRUD");
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model("Rol_model");
        $this->load->model("Questions_model");
    }

public function get_dificultad_seleccionada() {

        print_r($_REQUEST); print_r($_POST);
        //echo json_encode($dificultad);
    }

}
```

It seems to be a problem with the object conversion that I do with stringify on the client because if I change the ajax call like this, sendind a JSON manually, it works:

**Main.ts**

```
sendAjaxRequest("POST", "get_dificultad_seleccionada", {"_dificultad_seleccionada":"Normal"}, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
```

It seems that I'm doing something wrong but I have no idea of what could be, how can I send this object to the server in JSON format?

I want to do an universal function for all AJAX request in my program, but I don't know very well if I'm doing it properly, is the type of the callback function ok? or am I wrong with this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: so... you passed a string to your params that isn't params, and are confused why said string was treated as if it were params? you didn't tell your server that you were giving it json. Also isn't very common to be sending json with a get request. Not unheard of, just uncommon.

Comment: I'm new with AJAX and I don't understand completely how it works, but JSON.stringify(_dificultad) is basically a string with this {"_dificultad_seleccionada":"Normal"}, so It should be the same data, I don't understand why it doesn't work with the same data. What do you mean by what I'm passing is not params? I should send it with a POST request?

Comment: With dataType:'json' the AJAX request fails...

Comment: dataType specifies what you expect the server to return, that's a bit different. contentType would be more appropriate. but... i'd still suggest using POST rather than GET if you're sending in a json string. Also note that within php, it would not be in either GET or POST, instead it'l be elsewhere (google how to get json data from request in php)

Comment: it doesn't work with the stringify because jquery won't turn json into a param string, it leaves it as is. The server then assumes it's a paramstring and parses it as such, leaving you with a key containing the json string with no value.

Comment: After reading your second code, there is no way PHP would **EVER** ouput `[{"_dificultad_seleccionada":"Normal"}]` with `print_r()` so I quit reading.

Comment: Maybe you didn't read it properly, print_r() is returning [{"_dificultad_seleccionada":"Normal"}] as the KEY parameter, it doesn't output the JSON. I can do a screenshot if you want, you don't have to be that impolite.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have solved the problem, I'm sending the same data like I did before but now I use `contentType: 'json'` to tell the server that I'm sending a JSON and in the server side (PHP) I use the following to get the json: `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

**Main.ts**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "a#boton_seleccion_dificultad" ).click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        if (pasapalabra.gameState == GameState.GAME_STARTING) {

            let _dificultad: Dificultad = new Dificultad("Normal");

            sendAjaxRequest("POST", "get_dificultad_seleccionada", JSON.stringify(_dificultad), function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

        }

    });
});

function sendAjaxRequest(_type: string, _url: string, _params: string, _callback: CallbackFunction) {

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: _type,
        url: BASE_URL + _url,
        data: _params,
        contentType: 'json'
    });
    request.done(function(res) {
        _callback(res);
    });
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.error(jqXHR);
        _callback({ err: true, message: "Request failed: " + textStatus });
    });

}
```

**Welcome.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library("grocery_CRUD");
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model("Rol_model");
        $this->load->model("Questions_model");
    }

public function get_dificultad_seleccionada() {

        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        print_r($data);
        echo $data["_dificultad_seleccionada"];
    }

}
```

Now the server gets the value properly and I supose that now it's getting it in JSON format.

Comment: well.. i mean...  in this answer you're not sending json at all. just to be clear. you could remove `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify` and get the same result.

Comment: True, it still works without that... then why with stringify doesn't works? I'm using POST now and I writed contentType: 'json', but it still isn't working, now neither $_POST or $_REQUEST have anything, they both return:

Array
(
)